# How does the comma operator work with cout in C++?

Tags: c++, debugging

What's the return value (not printed) of

```
cout << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5;
```

How can I debug this code?

I need explain how work ostream and cout also.

Comment: Why do you expect the comma operator to work differently with `std::cout` than it normally does? And what have you tried doing?

Comment: What happened when you tried to run it? What did you expect and why'd you expect it?

Comment: Review http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence  and then add brackets.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the Comma Operator work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work)

Answer (score 0):

The return value is an `int` with the value `5`. As side effect, `1` will be printed.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    auto rv = (cout << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

    std::cout << rv;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `(cout << 1), 2, 3, 4, 5`

Comment: Depends. If you parenthesize as `(cout << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` you get `5`. If you don't add parentheses but assign to a variable like `auto r = cout << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5` the `=` operator binds stronger than `,` and you get `std::ostream&` as type for `r`.

Comment: @NiklasR I tried that first, but it would actually not compile for me, `std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator =(const std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function`

Comment: @nvoigt that is because declaring a variable as `auto` doesn't deduce a reference, so the type of `r` will actually be `std::ostream` even though the value being assigned is a `std::ostream&`. A `std::ostream` can't be copied, hence the "deleted function" error. Declaring `r` as `auto&` would make it a `std::ostream&` reference.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Did you try? Because I get the same error setting it explicitely to an `ostream&` and I still get it even when I split declaration and assignment.